# How is the control inside this function function working?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I need to write a function which search for an object using _id in mongodb and inside that object it will find an another array of IDs from different collection, 
then it will find names from different collection using that ID array.

Instead of going for more loops i directly tried accessing using index.

```
Order.findById(orderId)
        .then(order => {
            if(!order){
                    console.log('No Order');
                return next(new Error('No Order Found'));
            }
            console.log(order.productId[0]);
            console.log('reached here 1');
            Product.findById(order.productId[0])
                .then( product => {
                    if(!product){
                        return res.redirect('/admin/create-subadmin');
                    }
                    console.log('inside FindById');
                    const ProductName1 = product.name;
                    console.log(ProductName1);
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));        
            console.log('reached here');

         })
         .catch(err => {
             console.log(err);
         });
```

Current Output:

```
5cb9e18d6c17f41bacbcdf55 //(id of product[0])
reached here 1 
reached here 
inside FindById 
Titleasd   //(name of of product[0])
```

I can't understand why its going inside Product.findById in last. 
i.e. console.log('reached here');  // execution of this line is before Product.findById

```
Scheme of Order
{
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    orderId:String,
    productId:Array

}
```

```
Schema of Product
{

    product_id: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    },
    title: String,
    name:{
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    price:Number
}
```

I expect the function to go inside Order --> go for productId Array --> Using those IDs find all the product names and price and store them in an object or array anything, but i can't even understand the flow of control right now.

Answer (score 0):

So about the flow, there one thing you missed. `Product.findById` is asynchronous. So when you call it, the current function will not stop and execute the next line which is `console.log('reached here');`.

Look at the following example to understand :

**This is your case**

```js
function promise() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    console.log('#1 Start promise function execution');

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('#2 Finish promise function execution');

      resolve();
    }, 1500);
  });
}

function test() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    promise()
      .then(() => {
        console.log('#3 After the promise function call');
      })
      .then(resolve);

    console.log('#4 End of all');
  });
}

test();
```

---

**This is the soluce**

```js
function promise() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    console.log('#1 Start promise function execution');

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('#2 Finish promise function execution');

      resolve();
    }, 1500);
  });
}

function test() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    promise()
      .then(() => {
        console.log('#3 After the promise function call');
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log('#4 End of all');
        
        resolve();
      });
  });
}

test();
```

---

---

**So what about your code ? You could chain the calls**

```
Order.findById(orderId)
  .then((order) => {
    if (!order) {
      console.log('No Order');

      return next(new Error('No Order Found'));
    }

    console.log(order.productId[0]);
    console.log('reached here 1');

    return Product.findById(order.productId[0]);
  })
  .then((product) => {
    if (!product) {
      return res.redirect('/admin/create-subadmin');
    }

    console.log('inside FindById');

    const ProductName1 = product.name;

    console.log(ProductName1);
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('reached here');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: so i should try placing Product.findById in a then block after Order.FindById ?
and can you please tell me what i should do to get all the products name and store them in a global variable, so i can use them outside of these functions

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try storing the results now